# Jquery :retaining previous value on Cancel

Tags: jquery

Could any one help me for the below query

### Behaviour:

when user changes the dropdown value jquery msgbox will be shown with two buttons "Ok" and "Cancel".
requirement here is,when user clicks on "Ok" the value should be set to selected one,if user clicks on "Cancel" it should retain the old value.

Ours is custom code in main application and we have only modified value availability.
need a help from any jquery expert to correct the below code(as below code not working for cancel and value is getting blanked)

here is the code

```
function onChangeAlert(mode,$){
        var element = $('#'+this.id);
        $.msgBox({
            content: "do you want to continue? ",
            type: "confirm",
            buttons: [{ value: "Ok" },{ value: "Cancel" }],
            success: function (result) {
                 if (result == "Ok") {
                     $.data(element, 'current', $(element).val());
                    }else{
                        $(element).val($.data(element, 'current')); 
                    return false;
                }
        }});
    }
```

Comment: what does `console.log(result)` says ?

Comment: it will be "cancel" rt?

Comment: Where do you retain the old value once you detect cancel ?

Comment: its should not affect the values in dropdown(should be same as before change)